# How to get how many pages a file will take when sent to a printer in Java?

Tags: java, printing, desktop

I am working on a project where I get a file and then print it using `desktop.print(file);`
However, if this file is very large, say 50 pages, then I will not want to send the job to the printer.

Is there a way to get the number of pages that a file will take to be printed before I start the job?

Here is the part of the code where I do this:

```
File file = new File(filePath);         
try {
    desktop.print(file);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("error in trying to print");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Try to find some java library which will help you with this problem. I asked google for 'java printing library' and it shows me few libraries.

Comment: @user717630 That will not work because the files will be of different types, and size does not necessarily correspond to page length

Comment: @Patryk Roszczyniała those all seem to be console printing type libs. the only thigh i see mentioned is javax.print, which is not a 3rd party library. if you see any, please point me to them

Comment: user2464620, maybe it will be answer for your question http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/set.html ?

Comment: @user2464620 That looks better answer than all the other ones, but unfortunately I wont always have access to what is in the files. it could be pdf, or .docx or really any file type, and could be mixtures of text and pictures. So I'm never actually handling any of the the file content, just using desktop to print it out.

Answer (score 0):

How about if you get the file size and see if it's smaller or larger than a 50 pages file size. This way based on file size you can decide if you want to print it or not.Here is how you can get the file size :

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        File file =new File("c:\\java_xml_logo.jpg");

        if(file.exists()){

            double bytes = file.length();
            double kilobytes = (bytes / 1024);
            double megabytes = (kilobytes / 1024);
            double gigabytes = (megabytes / 1024);
            double terabytes = (gigabytes / 1024);
            double petabytes = (terabytes / 1024);
            double exabytes = (petabytes / 1024);
            double zettabytes = (exabytes / 1024);
            double yottabytes = (zettabytes / 1024);

            System.out.println("bytes : " + bytes);
            System.out.println("kilobytes : " + kilobytes);
            System.out.println("megabytes : " + megabytes);
            System.out.println("gigabytes : " + gigabytes);
            System.out.println("terabytes : " + terabytes);
            System.out.println("petabytes : " + petabytes);
            System.out.println("exabytes : " + exabytes);
            System.out.println("zettabytes : " + zettabytes);
            System.out.println("yottabytes : " + yottabytes);
        }else{
             System.out.println("File does not exists!");
        }

    }
}
```

[source](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-file-size-in-java/)